# How to change the text of dialog?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an *about* item in my options menu. When I click on *about*, a dialog will appear, but only it shows the text "This is a dialog".
I want it to show my text which is "MYapp is a fun app that had been developed by me."
This is the code. I already put my text in the code, but it won't show it. How can I show my text in dialog?

```
//Dialog
public void openDialog() {
    AboutDialog aboutDialog = new AboutDialog();
    aboutDialog.show( getSupportFragmentManager(), "MYapp is a fun app that had been developed by me." );
}
```

Comment: please provide the code for AboutDialog

Comment: What does your `AboutDialog` class look like?